# Is there a Laravel-way of testing how many times an event has fired?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the base PHPUnit config file with the default TestCase.php file.

I am seeking a way to check if an event is fired multiple times during a test. Current code looks like:

```
function test_fires_multiple_events()
{
    $this->expectsEvents(SomeEvent::class);
}
```

Ideally, I would want:

```
function test_fires_multiple_events()
{
    $this->expectsEvents(SomeEvent::class)->times(3);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After walking through the code in `MocksApplicationServices`, I was able to piggyback the trait, and the fields it captures when the `withoutEvents()` method.

The extension would look like:

```
function test_fires_multiple_events()
{
    $this->withoutEvents(); // From MocksApplicationServices

    $c = collect($this->firedEvents)
                ->groupBy(function($item, $key) { return get_class($item); })
                ->map(function($item, $key) { return $item->count(); });

    $this->assertsEqual(3, $c->get(SomeEvent::class));

}
```

To step through what collection is doing:

1) `collect($this->firedEvents)`: Takes the captured events and stores them in a collection. It's important to note, that `MocksApplicationServices` pushes each event into an array, meaning it is already keeping count.

2) `groupBy(function($item, $key) { return get_class($item); })`: Groups by the class name, meaning we have a collection of arrays now.

3) `map(function($item, $key) { .. }`: Simply tally up the children.

This results in a structure like:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection (1) (
    protected items -> array (2) [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => integer 2
        'App\Events\SomeOtherEvent' => integer 1
    ]
)
```

**Edit**
Just to clean it up a bit - you could add the following to your base test case file:

```
public function assertEventFiredTimes($event, $count)
{
    $this->assertEquals(
        count(collect($this->firedEvents)
            ->groupBy(function($item, $key) { return get_class($item); })
            ->get($event, [])),
        $count
    );
}
```

And then in your tests:

```
$this->assertEventFiredTimes(SomeEvent::class, 3);
```

Not forgetting to add `withoutEvents()`.

Comment: Great method and elegant solution, just one thing : sometimes the firedEvents array may contains both strings and objects events (like "kernel.handled" or "locale.changed").

So you might wanna use : 
{ return is_string($item) ? $item : get_class($item); } in the groupBy function so it can work with any type of event.

Answer (score 2):

Someone in laracasts faced this same problem and found the solution:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/testing-class-based-events-in-laravel-5

Basically: you just need to mock the Event dispatcher to expect the event class that you're using. After that you can check all you need.

Comment: I appreciate the link - and am reading through it now. But stackoverflow generally prefer that the answer includes the majority of the solution (with a reference link if needed). This is to avoid future dead links. Thanks again though

Answer (score 2):

Laravel got you covered with event fakes:

```
Event::fake(MyEvent::class)

// ... 

// Pass integer as callback to assertDispatched
Event::assertDispatched(MyEvent::class, 3);

// Or use the undocumented method assertDispatchedTimes directly
Event::assertDispatchedTimes(MyEvent::class, 3)
```

code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/EventFake.php#L47-L79

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to inject the event dispatcher to your class an then mock it so you could do something like:

```
$dispatcher->shouldReceive('fire')->with(SomeEvent::class)->times(3);
```